# Detect if is currently in a list

Tags: lists, conditionals

Is there anyway to detect if the code is currently inside a list, no matter `itemize`, `enumerate` or `description`?

Note: I'm using `enumitem` for configuring lists.

*Motivation: The reason I'm asking this is because that an environment in my document needs different vertical spacing outside or inside lists.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\IfInList}[2]{...} % How to define this?

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \IfInList{code if in list}{code if not in list}
\end{itemize}
\IfInList{code if in list}{code if not in list}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can check `\leftmargin` but  the exact definition depends on what you mean by "in a list" is text in a minipage in a list "in a list" is text in a center (or quote or flushleft) environment all of which are implemented as one item lists "in a list"

Comment: You can more easily check "immediately after an `\item` as that is `\if@inlabel` see the spacing trivlist does fornested cases: `\if@inlabel
    \@noparitemtrue
    \@noparlisttrue
  \else
    \if@newlist \@noitemerr \fi
    \@noparlistfalse
    \@topsep \@topsepadd
  \fi`

Comment: Reading the source code it seems that you can check if macro `enit@list` has the same meaning as `enit@enlist` or `enit@dylist`, but is `enumitem` package guaranteed?

Comment: Actually until inline list it seems to be equal to neither somehow...

Comment: @user202729 It seems `\ifx\enit@list\enit@dylist` does work, at least this is the case in my document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can emulate a stack by increasing to a counter when entering one of the specified environments and decreasing it at the end.

The `\IfInList` command can test whether the counter is positive.

The `\listenvironments` command can be issued multiple times, better not with the same environment name (I'm sure you can solve the problem yourself, if needed).

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listenvironments}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \AddToHook{env/##1/begin}{\int_gincr:N \g_jinwen_list_int}
    \AddToHook{env/##1/end}{\int_gdecr:N \g_jinwen_list_int}
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfInList}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \g_jinwen_list_int > 0 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\int_new:N \g_jinwen_list_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listenvironments}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \AddToHook{env/##1/begin}{\int_gincr:N \g_jinwen_list_int}
    \AddToHook{env/##1/end}{\int_gdecr:N \g_jinwen_list_int}
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfInList}{mm}
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \g_jinwen_list_int > 0 } { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\int_new:N \g_jinwen_list_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\listenvironments{itemize,enumerate,description}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \IfInList{code if in list}{code if not in list}
\end{itemize}

\IfInList{code if in list}{code if not in list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The idea of your code is very clear and easy to understand, and can also apply to other situations.